# mongoid inheritance problem

Tags: inheritance, mongoid, has-many

I have a model like this

```
class Canvas
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  referenced_in :hero
end

class Browser < Canvas
  field :version, :type => Integer
end

class Hero
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  references_many :canvases
end
```

How can I build Brower Object refered from Hero object.

All i want to do is

```
h = Hero.create!({:name => 'Aston'})
h.browsers.build
```

However it gave me an error

```
undefined method `browsers' for #<Hero _id: 4d92c8fc1426960fff000005, name: "Aston">
```

Am i missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
h.canvases.build({},Browser)
```

this works for mongoid.2.0.0.rc7

Comment: note this answer works only for Mongoid 2.0.0rc7 and doesn't work in mongoid-2.0.0.beta.19.

Comment: I found this answer through http://modetojoy.blogspot.com/2010/01/inheritance-in-mongoid.html